# undefined property calling an object detecting if mouse is over a text

Tags: javascript, class, properties, html5-canvas, undefined

trying to call a function, in the mousemove event, to detect if a mouse is over a text or not  I obtain an error

*palabraInestable.js:126 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posX' of undefined
    at contains (palabraInestable.js:126)*

saying that the object palInst is undefined
however palInst is an object declared as universal and could be readed in all the code blocks.
in fact if you comment all related to events ( all references to contains () ) you could see 
`palInst.pintaPalabraInestable()`
; 
working, therefore palInst is an object working allready.
so, ... what Im doing wrong ???

link to the complete code https://jsfiddle.net/oeL2yq97/29/

```js
// class ///////////
class PalabraInestable {

  constructor(texto, posX, posY) {

    this.texto = texto || "";
    this.posX = posX || 0;
    this.posY = posY || 0;

    this.altoPalabra = 20;
    this.anchoPalabra = 40;
  }

  // metodos ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  pintaPalabraInestable() {

    ctx.fillText(this.texto, this.posX, this.posY);
  }

  tickle() {

    this.posX += Math.random() * 5 - 3; // un número aleatorio entre -5 y 5
    this.posY += Math.random() * 5 - 3; // un número aleatorio entre -5 y 5

  }

}

//variables universales ----------------------------------------------------------

// posiciones iniciales del texto total
var x = 100;
var y = 200;

delay = 100;


// palabra objeto prueba
var palInst = new PalabraInestable();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function init() { // setup() mas o menos

  // configuracion del canvas 
  canvas = document.getElementById("papel");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


  ctx.font = " 45px Amatic SC "; // para todo el canvas
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

  palInst.texto = "palabra inestable";
  palInst.posX = 100;
  palInst.posY = 100;

  // eventos de raton LLAMADAS A FUNCIONES 
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  //canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  //canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   mouseUp,   false);
  //canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',  mouseUp,  false);  
  //canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick, false); 


  setInterval(draw, delay); // llama al draw() y fija fotogramas 
} // fin de init ---------------------------------------------------------


function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.save();

  // aqui el follon  

  palInst.pintaPalabraInestable();

  //  restaura el canvas salvado
  ctx.restore();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw); // llamada recursiva al draw
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw); // ejecucion del draw
/**/


// funciones ========================================================================

// ensayo mousemove -------------------------------------------------------------------
function mouseMove(evento, palInst) {
  let mouseX = getMousePosX(canvas, evento);
  let mouseY = getMousePosY(canvas, evento);

  // If mouse is over the word
  if (contains(mouseX, mouseY, palInst)) {
    palInst.tickle(); //     
  }
}


// mouse position separated to be clear -----------------------------------------
function getMousePosX(canvas, evento) {

  let ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log("entra en getmouse pos x");
  // devuelve un objeto con las coordenadas x e y
  return Math.round(evento.clientX - ClientRect.left);

}

function getMousePosY(canvas, evento) {

  let ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // devuelve un objeto con las coordenadas  y       
  return Math.round(evento.clientY - ClientRect.top);

} //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// funcion para verificar que pinchamos dentro de un objeto
function contains(mouseX, mouseY, palInst) {
  if ((palInst.posX <= mouseX) && (palInst.posX + palInst.anchoPalabra >= mouseX) && (palInst.posY <= mouseY) && (palInst.posY + palInst.altoPalabra >= mouseY)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> mouseover palabra inestable</title>

  <canvas id="papel" width="700" height="700">
 Su navegador no soporta en elemento CANVAS</canvas>

  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    
    .subdiv {
      width: 320px;
    }
    
    .text {
      margin: auto;
      width: 290px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body onload="init();">

  <script src="scripts/clasePalabraInestable.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/palabraInestable.js"></script>
  <p align="left" font face="Courier, Arial, Verdana" size="3">
    prueba de palabra inestable
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the console message on the fiddle you provide. init is undefined. Look at the src of the scripts that you specify. Use an absolute path to a valid URL. It should not be relative.

Comment: my fault. this code was made to work in my computer. this is why paths are relatives. I ll take note . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

Your `mouseMove` function is an event listener:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
```

thus, when the event happens, it will be invoked only with one parameter: the event. But it expects two arguments:

```
function mouseMove(evento, palInst) {
```

and so the second one (i.e. `palInst`) will be `undefined`, and since it shadows the outer `palInst` that holds your instance, when you do:

```
contains(mouseX, mouseY, palInst);
```

you're acltually passing `undefined` as the third parameter.

**Fix:**

Change you `mouseMove` to not expect a second argument:

```
function mouseMove(evento) {
```

**Note:**

Your code relies on a lot of global variables which may cause even more trouble. I think you'll better think about refactoring it so it doesn't. Also `ctx` is not declared.

Comment: you`re right. clear now
global variables : very useful comment. is a c++ heritage. thanks